# ActiveRecord not returning an iteration when there is only one record found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might be simple but I'm starting out with rails.

I have the following statement:

```
@subjects = Cartitem.find_by_cid(session[:customerid])
```

In my View I have some code like this:

```
<% @subjects.each do |d| %>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
```

All works when when the above query returns multiple rows. However, when above query returns only one row then I get an error in my View saying method `each` is not defined.

What is the way to avoid this? Do I need to have some `if/else` in my view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably

```
@subjects = Cartitem.find_all_by_cid(session[:customerid])
```

will work, because Rails documentation says, that line You gave:

```
@subjects = Cartitem.find_by_cid(session[:customerid])
```

will actually call:

```
Cartitem.find(:first, :conditions => ["cid = ?", session[:customerid]])
```

I don't think the solution with `to_a` (mentioned by user141146) will work at all because, object that is being returned is not an instance of any kind of QuerySet (e.g. like in Django) but pure model instance thus it probably wont has this method at all.

Comment: You can ensure a list by doing something like [@subjects].flatten